# load jsp from normal java project into web project

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web

I have created a normal java project and made as a library project. Now my requirement is like need to load jsp from that lib project into another web project.

Can anybody help me whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: i did not understood ur question

Comment: Can I use web-fragments here ??